# golang mgo TTL index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, go

how do I create a TTL (time to live) index with golang and mongodb?
This is how I'm trying to do it currently:

```
sessionTTL := mgo.Index{
    Key:         []string{"created"},
    Unique:      false,
    DropDups:    false,
    Background:  true,
    ExpireAfter: session_expire} // session_expire is a time.Duration

if err := db.C("session").EnsureIndex(sessionTTL); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

But if I look it up using:

```
db.session.getIndexes()
```

session_expire is set to 5*time.Second. The field "created" in the document is set to current date using time.Now(), so I expected the documents the be deleted after 5 seconds.

Comment: You create the index on `db.C("session")`, but you are looking at `db.mydb.getIndexes()`.

Comment: Ah right, that's a mistake here on stackoverflow. If I look up the session collection there are no indexes.

Comment: Code works for me. Please add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg can you give me an updated example for TTL entry. Thanks

Comment: @RafidKotta No. Either the sample works for you or you have a different question, which I might or might not answer. However, you can get my daily rate on request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was that I had to drop the collection. The index existed already so it was not recreated with the expiration constraint.

Comment: Well doesn't really matter, since this is in development and the collection is cleaned each test :)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to use the answer to this question, and ran into a problem.  Consider the following small change:

```
sessionTTL := mgo.Index{
    Key:         []string{"created"},
    Unique:      false,
    DropDups:    false,
    Background:  true,
    ExpireAfter: 60 * 60} // one hour

if err := db.C("session").EnsureIndex(sessionTTL); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

The problem with this is that the code silently fails if `ExpireAfter` is not a proper `time.Duration`.

I had to change to:
        ExpireAfter: time.Duration(60 * 60) * time.Second,

Comment: Yes the variable "session_expire" is of type time.Duration. I add that to my question.

Comment: Or you can just do `3600 * time.Second`